How do I copy an individual Cell's conditional formatting using Openpyxl?
I'm trying to move one set of Excel cells to another location in a workbook using python's openpyxl, offset by some columns. The source sheet has some cells that use conditional formatting.
In good news, move_range does much of the work. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to copy/move the conditional formatting; it just get altogether lost.
Anyone have thoughts?

You will have to use a loop and copy each cell's format to the target cell. For example, target_cell.font = source_cell.font.copy()
target_cell.border = source_cell.border.copy()

Conditional formats are worksheet objects that are applied to ranges of cells. This is covered in the documentation.

To move the conditional formatting you'd need to move the rules to the new range.
This is relatively easy; loop the conditional formatting in the Sheet and check if the CF range is within the moved range. If it is move the rules for that CF to the new CF range which includes copying them to the new range and deleting the rules from the old range.
Example code moves a range of cells from "F1:I5" to "C9:F13". This range contains Conditional Formatting on the cells in range "H2:I5". The new range for the Conditional Formatting will be "E10:F13".
First we get each CF Rules range and determine if that range (E.g. "H2:I5") is within the range "F1:I5" being moved. Then for each CF rule, recreate using the new range for the cells, "E10:F13".
Once the rules are copied we can then delete the CF with the old range "H2:I5"
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

def calc_cf_range(cf_rng):
    cf_col_srt, cf_row_srt, cf_col_end, cf_row_end = openpyxl.utils.cell.range_boundaries(cf_rng)

    new_cf_col_srt = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(cf_col_srt + cols_offset)
    new_cf_row_srt = cf_row_srt + rows_offset
    new_cf_col_end = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(cf_col_end + cols_offset)
    new_cf_row_end = cf_row_end + rows_offset

    return f"{new_cf_col_srt}{new_cf_row_srt}:{new_cf_col_end}{new_cf_row_end}"


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

src_cellrange = "F1:I5"
dst_cellrange = "C9:F13"

src_col_srt, src_row_srt, src_col_end, src_row_end = openpyxl.utils.cell.range_boundaries(src_cellrange)
dst_col_srt, dst_row_srt, dst_col_end, dst_row_end = openpyxl.utils.cell.range_boundaries(dst_cellrange)

rows_offset = dst_row_srt - src_row_srt
cols_offset = dst_col_srt - src_col_srt

ws.move_range(src_cellrange, rows=rows_offset, cols=cols_offset, translate=False)

for cf in ws.conditional_formatting._cf_rules:
    for range in cf.cells.ranges:
        cf_range = range.coord
        if cf_range in CellRange(src_cellrange):
            dst_cfrange = calc_cf_range(cf_range)

            print(f"This CF Range '{range}' is included in the cell move. Relocating these CF Rules")

            print(f"Copy Rules to new CF Range '{dst_cfrange}'")
            for rule in cf.cfRule:
                ws.conditional_formatting.add(dst_cfrange, rule)

            del ws.conditional_formatting[cf_range]
            print(f"Deleted Rules from old Range '{cf_range}'")

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')

